# Working with 64bit numbers under 32bit WinXP

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I am new to assembly and I wonder why this function for adding two 64bit ints doesn't calculate properly:

**add.asm**

```
bits 32
section .text
global _add64
_add64: ; adding a and b
    enter 0,0
    mov eax,[ebp+8]  ; la
    mov edx,[ebp+12] ; ha
    add eax,[ebp+16] ; la+= lb
    adc edx,[ebp+20] ; ha+= hb with cf
    leave
ret
```

I use NASM compiler under WinXP 32bit, compiled as

```
nasm -f win32 add.asm
```

used together with c program

**add64.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long add64(long long a, long long b);

void main() {
    printf("%Ld",add64(100000000000LL,100000000000LL));
}
```

compiled together under gcc as

```
gcc add64.obj add64.c -o add64.exe
```

the result is `-1863462912`

How so and what to do to get the expected `200000000000`?

Comment: Compile an equivalent function in C and see in debugger how does it work. Your implementation of the GCC calling convention is probably off; for one thing, I doubt that EAX:EDX is really how 64-bit return values are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly function looks OK to me. I strongly suspect the `%Ld` specifier is wrong. -1863462912 is the low 32 bits of 200000000000.

Try `%lld`.

Comment: yep, you hit the nail!